# How Can I Solve Larger File Import Error In Wamp - Out Of Memory

Tags: database, magento, import, wamp, wampserver

I need to import Exported Database, when i try to import i get error like below image

[image]

As per error line, what can i do,

[image]

My Configuration :

[image]

How can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very large backup files are best reloaded using the MYSQL Console, as there are no PHP limitations using this tool.

```
left click wampmanager->MYSQL-> MySQL Console
```

You then run the restore by doing

```
mysql> use `your_database_name`;
mysql> source C:/path/to/backup.sql
```

Note the use of forward slash and not back slash

However if you want to use `phpMyAdmin` then you have to amend the phpMyAdmin config specifically

Edit **`\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`** it should look something like this ***your version numbers may well be different to this example***

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.5/"

<Directory "D:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </ifDefine>

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

In here you will see all the PHP parameters that have been set for phpMyAdmin specifically.

Just amend the ones that apply to your specific issue and then restart Apache and try again.

It is done this was so that you can amend these parameters without affecting the whole Apache/PHP environment just to get a big restore run.

Comment: this is my values,    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 8048M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 8048M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360000000
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360000000    still not working'

Comment: I suggest you use the MYSQL Console solution then, if your backup is that large a php script _which phpMyAdmin is_ is never likely to complete

Comment: See the first 6 lines of my answer

Comment: phpMyAdmin **will ignore that config** as it has been overridden in the `phpMyAdmin` config file

Comment: Those parameter you have set in the `php.ini` are just to large to be sensible. Remember those parameters effect EVERY PHP script that now runs on you server.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you must increase **memory_limit** in php.ini. magento suggest min **512M** memory_limit.

My php.ini settings like this

```
memory_limit = 1024M;
max_execution_time = 18000;
upload_max_filesize = 100M;
post_max_size = 100M;
max_input_vars = 10000;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 12000000;
```